# Import data in magento 2

Tags: magento2, importexport, import-products

Hi i want to import product on magento 2.2.9 if can any one help me with a good tutorial Also all my pictures are on externe server. I use Builderall platforme wich has magento 2 already installed tank you

Comment: https://github.com/firegento/FireGento_FastSimpleImport2 will do the same thing faster, which is key for large product volumes

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link which have step by step guide on how to import products in Magento 2 using csv in bulk : [Import Data Magento 2 Official Guide](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import.html)

And for more refer to this below link for importing images from external source : [How to Import All Products with Images in Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-import-all-products-with-images-magento-2.html#method-2-import-images-from-external-server)

Comment: Tank you for your helo and if i get sticks i will contact you

Comment: Sure, anytime. Pleasure to help you.

Comment: Hello please i am stuck with the Csv file i can't apploawd it correctly i try to export product than made change on it but still have mistakse please if you can guide me thank you

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Error saying that my Csv file is not correct in sku and all other attributes

Comment: Your csv file is not in the right format it needs to be, please compare it with the file you exported and make sure the format is same and there is no spell mistake. If none help, try sharing your csv in  your answer so that me or someone can help by looking at it.